# 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) error for dymo printer on server 2012 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {09DAFAE2-8EB0-11D2-8E5D-00A02415E90F} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Above is the error.  So far I have gone into the registry and made sure the service account the website is running under has permissions to the underlying com, I have done the same in the dcom config.  When I run this locally it works perfectly fine, and on a previous sever when it ran under ApplicationPoolIdentity it worked fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) find your service account that is running the app pool for your site. 2) find the DLL for this COM component.  Right click the COM component file , go to the security tab, and give the service account run and execute access.  If you don't have a separate service account running the site, I suggest you get one set up.

Comment: The service account has full access to the dll and I still get this same error.  not sure if it will matter but this is on a load balanced system through netscaler.

I am also intermittently getting a Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) for the same COM, but if I re run after that I get access denied error.

Comment: is asp.net running with impersonation mode?  Forms auth?

Comment: No impersonation. Don't think forms auth.